# Javascript if statement not returning a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am trying to add a javascript code to display text on my website if the product price is over $35. I cannot get this if statement to return anything, can someone tell me why? This is at the bottom of an HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    if (TRUE) {
        TRUESTATEMENT;
    }
    else{
        NOTTRUE;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you'll need to manipulate the dom. a script tag won't do that by itself.

Comment: you passing your value as parameter?

Comment: If you want to just verify it is working, put in a Console.Log() and you can see if the script itself is working.

Comment: maybe because TRUE is not true but a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an self executing function you can wrap it in brackets and then call it `(function(){...})();`

```js
(function(){

  if( true ){
   console.log( 'thing was true' );
  } else {
   console.log( 'thing was false' );
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        if (TRUE) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = TRUESTATEMENT;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = NOTTRUE;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Without knowing the structure of your html it is hard to give an accurate answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    if (true) {
        $('#test').text(true);
    }
    else{
        $('#test').text(false);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: @jake-p did it help?

Comment: It has not worked yet, I am trying to see if there is something else in my code causing the problem. I get no text display on my website from this.